# CSS : How to put a div on top of the modal-backdrop

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to do something really simple, but I can't figure out why I can't!

I would like to have the grey rectangle on the side on top of the modal-backdrop.

the CSS class of my rectange :

```
.preview-window{
position: absolute;
bottom: 15px;
right: 15px;
background-color: grey;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
overflow: visible;
z-index: 999999;}
```

The component:

```
const Preview: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({ position, sizex, sizey }) => {
  return (
    <div className={"preview-window"} style={{ width: sizex, height: sizey}}>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The component is the main body

```
return (
    <div className="body">
      //The grey rectangle
      <Preview sizex={250} sizey={100} position={true} />
      //The modal
      <EditWindow show={modalShow} setShow={modalSetShow} />
      

      //divs...

    </div>
  );
```

The z-index of modal-backdrop is about 1050.

The code rendered and cleaned :

```
<body data-new-gr-c-s-loaded="9.36.0" class="modal-open" style="overflow: hidden;" data-rr-ui-modal-open="">
    <div id="root">
        <ion-app class="md ion-page hydrated">
            <ion-router-outlet class="hydrated">
                <div class="ion-page can-go-back" style="z-index: 101;">
                    <ion-content fullscreen="true" class="snippet-body md hydrated"
                        style="--offset-top: 0px; --offset-bottom: 0px;">
                        <header class="header" id="header">
                        </header>
        
                        </div>
                        <div class="body">
                            <div class="preview-window" style="width: 250px; height: 100px;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </ion-content>
                </div>
            </ion-router-outlet>
        </ion-app>
    </div>

    <div class="fade modal-backdrop show"></div>
    <div role="dialog" aria-modal="true" class="fade modal show" tabindex="-1"
        style="display: block; padding-left: 15px;">
        <div class="modal-dialog react-draggable modal-dialog-centered" style="transform: translate(369px, 40px);">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <div>Edit Label :</div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button"
                        class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Close</button><button type="button"
                        class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Save Changes</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried react-layers-manager, but I can't import the module.

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-layers-manager'. '.../node_modules/react-layers-manager/lib/index.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-layers-manager` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-layers-manager';`ts(7016)
```

Thanks

[image: Image2]
[image: Image1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without your HTML and a bit more CSS, we cannot answer this for you. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Add your rendered HTML, not the component. It's super tedious for us to help debug when we have to look at the component and try to figure out how it actually renders in the browser.

Comment: I cleaned the code a little bit. Maybe the problem comes from the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit too much going on up there for me to really comment on your specific use case. But, I will say, sometimes positioning is easier if you just `useRef`:

```js
const modalRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

// ...

<div className="your-modal" ref={modalRef}>
    // ...
</div>

// elsewhere
const {
    offsetLeft,
    offsetTop
} = modalRef.current ? modalRef.current : { offsetLeft : 0, offsetTop : 0);

<div style={{
    position : "fixed",
    left : offsetLeft,
    top : offsetTop
}}>
   Whatever
</div>
```

In my experience, the performance effects of doing something like this are negligible and your rendering is more consistent across different browsers.

Comment: I can't really use useRef since I open/close the modal, and I want to keep the preview window on the top layer.

Comment: Neither of those requirements actually precludes using useRef. But, you may need to think about the best way to share the ref between whichever components.